# Width of div is 0 if screen size is below 960px, and random number above 960px

Tags: angular

I am currently working on a project where I am creating a custom chart using CSS and Angular and I have a problem with retrieving the width of the div that contains the chart. On the very first render if the screen is below 960px I get offsetWidth 0. Above 960px the offsetWidth is more than half of the length of the div (e.g. if the original div is 485px and the screen is 1000px, after first render the offsetWidth is 337px. Below 960px the offsetWidth of the div is 0. It does not matter what I use (document.getElementById() or ElementRef and ViewChild) nothing helps. I am also using resize event and after resize everything works fine, only the first render causes problem. Anybody had anything similar?

Comment: have you tried setting a defined width for the div or at least set it to 100%

Comment: Yes, the width is set to 100%. It should be only a simple getElementById or ElementRef, but somehow it's not working properly.